# Designing Interfaces in c++

Tags: c++, interface

I am developing an interface that can be used as dynamic loading.Also it should be compiler independent.So i wanted to export Interfaces.
I am facing now the following problems..

Problem 1: The interface functions are taking some custom data types (basically classes or structures) as In\Out parameters.I want to initialise members of these classes with default values using constructors.If i do this it is not possible to load my library dynamically and it becomes compiler dependent. How to solve this.

Problem 2: Some interfaces returns lists(or maps) of element to client.I am using std containers for this purpose.But this also once again compiler dependent(and compiler version also some times).

Thanks.

Comment: The typical solution for this problem is simply to recompile the library with the relevant compiler....

Comment: ... or provide a C only interface, that uses C++ under the hood and provides C++ wrappers for C++ clients.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been downvoted, designing an API that is binary compatible across different compiler/versions is a complicated and useful topic.

Answer (score 3):

Code compiled differently can only work together if it adopts the same [Application Binary Interface (ABI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) for the set of types used for parameters and return value.  ABI's are significant at a much deeper level - name mangling, virtual dispatch tables etc., but my point's that if there's one your compilers support allowing calling of functions with simple types, you can at least think about hacking together some support for more complex types like compiler-specific implementations of Standard containers and user-defined types.

You'll have to research what ABI support your compilers provide, and infer what you can about what they'll continue to provide.

If you want to support other types beyond what the relevant ABI standardises, options include:

- use simpler types to expose internals of more complex types

  - pass [`const`] `char*` and `size_t` extracted by `my_std_string.data()` or `&my_std_string[0]` and `my_std_string.size()`, similarly for `std::vector`
  - serialise the data and deserialise it using the data structures of the receiver (can be slow)
- provide a set of function pointers to simple accessor/mutator functions implemented by the object that created the data type

  - e.g. the way the classic C `qsort` function accepts a pointer to an element comparison function

Comment: std::string.c_str() ?

Comment: @KlaasvanGend: yes indeed if the receiver expects ASCIIZ / `NUL` terminated strings.

Answer (score 2):

As I usually have a multithreading focus, I'm mostly going to bark about your second problem.

You already realized that passing elements of a container over an API seems to be compiler dependent. It's actually worse: it's header file & C++-library dependent, so at least for Linux you're already stuck with two different sets: libstc++ (originating from gcc) and libcxx (originating from clang).
Because part of the containers is header files and part is library code, getting things ABI-independent is close to impossible.

My bigger worry is that you actually thought of passing container elements around. This is a huge threadsafety issue: the STL containers are ***not*** threadsafe - by design.

By passing references over the interface, you are passing "pointers to encapsulated knowledge" around - the users of your API could make assumptions of your internal structures and start modifying the data pointed to. That is usually already really bad in a singlethreaded environment, but gets worse in a multithreaded environment.

Secondly, pointers you provided could get stale, not good either.

Make sure to return copies of your inner knowledge to prevent user modification of your structures.

Passing things `const` is not enough: const can be cast away and you still expose your innards.

So my suggestion: hide the data types, only pass simple types and/or structs that you fully control (i.e. are not dependent on STL or boost).

Answer (score 2):

Designing an API with the widest ABI compatibility is an *extremely* complex subject, even more so when C++ is involved instead of C.

Yet there are more theoretical-type issues that aren't really quite as bad as they sound in practice. For example, in theory, calling conventions and structure padding/alignment sound like they could be major headaches. In practice they aren't so much, and you can even resolve such issues in hindsight by specifying additional build instructions to third parties or decorating your SDK functions with macros indicating the appropriate calling convention. By "not so bad" here, I mean that they can trip you up but they won't have you going back to the drawing board and redesigning your entire SDK in response.

The "practical" issues I want to focus on are issues that can have you revisiting the drawing board and redoing the entire SDK. My list is also not exhaustive, but are some of the ones I think you should really keep in mind first.

You can also treat your SDK as consisting of two parts: a dynamically-linked part that actually exports functionality whose implementation is hidden from clients, and a statically (internally) linked convenience library part that adds C++ wrappers on top. If you treat your SDK as having these two distinct parts, you're allowed a lot more liberty in the statically-linked library to use a lot more C++ mechanisms.

So, let's get started with those practical headache inducers:

**1. The binary layout of a vtable is not necessarily consistent across compilers.**

This is, in my opinion, one of the biggest gotchas. We're usually looking at 2 main ways to access functionality from one module to another at runtime: function pointers (including those provided by dylib symbol lookup) and interfaces containing virtual functions. The latter can be so much more convenient in C++ (both for implementor and client using the interface), yet unfortunately using virtual functions in an API that aims to be binary compatible with the widest range of compilers is like playing minesweeper through a land of gotchas.

I would recommend avoiding virtual functions outright for this purpose unless your team consists of minesweeper experts who know all of these gotchas. It's useful to try to fall in love with C again for those public interface parts and start building a fondness for these kinds of interfaces consisting of function pointers:

```
struct Interface
{
    void* opaque_private_data;
    void (*func1)(struct Interface* self, ...);
    void (*func2)(struct Interface* self, ...);
    void (*func3)(struct Interface* self, ...);
};
```

These present far fewer gotchas and are nowhere near as fragile against changes (ex: you're perfectly allowed to do things like add more function pointers to the bottom of the structure without affecting ABI).

**2. Stub libs for dylib symbol lookup are linker-specific (as are all static libs in general).**

This might not seem like a big deal until combined with #1. When you toss out virtual functions for the purpose of exporting interfaces, then the next big temptation is to often export whole classes or select methods through a dylib.

Unfortunately doing this with manual symbol lookup can become very unwieldy very quickly, so the temptation is to often do this automatically by simply linking to the appropriate stub.

Yet this too can become unwieldy when your goal is to support as many compilers/linkers as possible. In such a case, you may have to possess many compilers and build and distribute different stubs for each possibility.

So this can kind of push you into a corner where it's no longer very practical export class definitions anymore. At this point you might simply export free-standing functions with C linkage (to avoid C++ name mangling which is another potential source of headaches).

One of the things that should be obvious already is that we're getting nudged more and more towards favoring a C or C-like API if our goal is universal binary compatibility without opening up too many cans of worms.

**3. Different modules have 'different heaps'.**

If you allocate memory in one module and try to deallocate it in another, then you're trying to free memory from a mismatching heap and will invoke undefined behavior.

Even in plain old C, it's easy to forget this rule and `malloc` in one exported function only to return a pointer to it with the expectation that the client accessing the memory from a different module will `free` it when done. This once again invokes undefined behavior, and we have to export a second function to indirectly free the memory from the same module that allocated it.

This can become a much bigger gotcha in C++ where we often have class templates that have internal linkage that implicitly do memory management. For example, even if we roll our own `std::vector`-like sequence like `List<T>`, we can run into a scenario where a client creates a list, passes it to our API by reference where we use functions that can allocate/deallocate memory (like `push_back` or `insert`) and butt heads with this mismatching heap/free store issue. So even this hand-rolled container should ensure that it allocates and deallocates memory from the same central location if it's going to be passed around across modules, and placement new will become your friend when implementing such containers.

**4. Passing/returning C++ standard objects is not ABI-compatible.**

This includes C++ standard containers as you have already guessed. There's no really practical way to ensure that one compiler will use a compatible representation of something like `std::vector` when including `<vector>` as another. So passing/returning such standard objects whose representation is outside of your control is generally out of the question if you're targeting wide binary compatibility.

These don't even necessarily have compatible representations within two projects built by the *same compiler*, as their representations can vary in incompatible ways based on build settings.

This might make you think that you should now roll all kinds of containers by hand, but I would suggest a KISS approach here. If you're returning a variable number of elements as a result from a function, then we don't need a wide range of container types. We only need one dynamic array kind of container, and it doesn't even have to be a growable sequence, just something with proper copy, move, and destruction semantics.

It might seem nicer and could save some cycles if you just returned a set or a map in a function that computes one, but I'd suggest forgetting about returning these more sophisticated structures and convert to/from this basic dynamic array kind of representation. It's rarely the bottleneck you might think it would be to transfer to/from contiguous representations, and if you actually do run into a hotspot as a result of this which you actually gained from a legit profiling session of a real world use case, then you can always add more to your SDK in a very discrete and selective fashion.

You can also always wrap those more sophisticated containers like map into a C-like function pointer interface that treats the handle to the map as opaque, hidden away from clients. For heftier data structures like a binary search tree, paying the cost of one level of indirection is generally very negligible (for simpler structures like a random-access contiguous sequence, it generally isn't quite as negligible, especially if your read operations like `operator[]` involve indirect calls).

Another thing worth noting is that everything I've discussed so far relates to the exported, dynamically-linked side of your SDK. The static convenience library that is internally linked is free to receive and return standard objects to make things convenient for the third party using your library, provided that you're not actually passing/returning them in your exported interfaces. You can even avoid rolling your own containers outright and just take a C-style mindset to your exported interfaces, returning raw pointers to `T*` that needs to be freed while your convenience library does that automatically and transfers the contents to `std::vector<T>`, e.g.

**5. Throwing exceptions across module boundaries is undefined.**

We should generally not be throwing exceptions from one module to be caught in another when we cannot ensure compatible build settings in the two modules, let alone the same compiler. So throwing exceptions from your API to indicate input errors is generally out of the question in this case.

Instead we should catch all possible exceptions at the entry points to our module to avoid leaking them into the outside world, and translate all such exceptions into error codes.

The statically-linked convenience library can still call one of your exported functions, check the error code, and in the case of failure, throw an exception. This is perfectly fine here since that convenience library is internally linked to the module of the third party using this library, so it's effectively throwing the exception from the third party module to be caught by the same third party module.

**Conclusion**

While this is, by no means, an exhaustive list, these are some caveats that can, when unheeded, cause some of the biggest issues at the broadest level of your API design. These kinds of design-level issues can be exponentially more expensive to fix in hindsight than implementation-type issues, so they should generally have the highest priority.

If you're new to these subjects, you can't go too far wrong favoring a C or very C-like API. You can still use a lot of C++ implementing it and can also build a C++ convenience library back on top (your clients don't even have to use anything but the C++ interfaces provided by that internally-linked convenience library).

With C, you're typically looking at more work at the baseline level, but potentially far fewer of those disastrous design-level gotchas. With C++, you're looking at less work at the baseline level, but far more potentially disastrous surprise scenarios. If you favor the latter route, you generally want to ensure that your team's expertise with ABI issues is higher with a larger coding standards document dedicating large sections to these potential ABI gotchas.

For your specific questions:

> Problem 1: The interface functions are taking some custom data types
>   (basically classes or structures) as In\Out parameters.I want to
>   initialise members of these classes with default values using
>   constructors.If i do this it is not possible to load my library
>   dynamically and it becomes compiler dependent. How to solve this.

This is where that statically-linked convenience library can come in handy. You can statically link all that convenient code like a class with constructors and still pass in its data in a more raw, primitive kind of form to the exported interfaces. Another option is to selectively inline or statically link the constructor so that its code is not exported as with the rest of the class, but you probably don't want to be exporting classes as indicated above if your goal is max binary compatibility and don't want too many gotchas.

> Problem 2: Some interfaces returns lists(or maps) of element to
>   client.I am using std containers for this purpose.But this also once
>   again compiler dependent(and compiler version also some times).

Here we have to forgo those standard container goodies at least at the exported API level. You can still utilize them at the convenience library level which has internal linkage.